# use F to update multiple fields Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, sql-update

HI i need to update the multiple fields in the database , right now i am updating like this

```
 for t in getteamPlayers :
     getmyplayer= myplayer.objects.get(id=t.playerId)
     getPlayerAge = getmyplayer.age     
     increase = max(0, (1+((MIDAGE - getPlayerAge) * MULTIPLIER) / 100) * 0.05 / 9)
     getvitals = vitals.objects.get(playerID=t.playerId)
     getvitals.velocity = min(max(getvitals.velocity + increase,0),1)  
     getvitals.power = min(max(getvitals.power + increase,0),1)  
     getvitals.arm = min(max(getvitals.arm + increase,0),1)  
     getvitals.ranges = min(max(getvitals.ranges + increase,0),1)  
     #getvitals.save()

     vitals.objects.update()
```

but it takes so much time i want to use something like `myplayer.objects.update(age=F('age')+0.0192)` which uses f and it updates very quickly can you please suggest me how can i use F to update multiple fields in in above code so that i can update the fields fast thanks